# working with binary numbers in java

Tags: java

I would like to know which one is the best way to work with binary numbers in java.
I need a way to create an array of binary numbers and do some calculations with them.
For example, I would like to X-or the values or multiply matrix of binary numbers.

Problem solved:
Thanks very much for all the info.

I think for my case I'm going to use the BitSet mentioned by @Jarrod Roberson

Comment: please select the correct answer (add the green checkmark)

Answer (score 55):

In Java edition 7, you can simply use binary numbers by declaring ints and preceding your numbers with `0b` or `0B`:

```
int x=0b101;
int y=0b110;
int z=x+y;

System.out.println(x + "+" + y + "=" + z);
//5+6=11

/*
* If you want to output in binary format, use Integer.toBinaryString()
*/

System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x) + "+" + Integer.toBinaryString(y)
         + "=" + Integer.toBinaryString(z));
//101+110=1011
```

Comment: You should mention that this works only from Java 7 on: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html

Answer (score 17):

What you are probably looking for is the [`BitSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class.

> This class implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each
>   component of the bit set has a boolean value. The bits of a BitSet are
>   indexed by nonnegative integers. Individual indexed bits can be
>   examined, set, or cleared. One BitSet may be used to modify the
>   contents of another BitSet through logical AND, logical inclusive OR,
>   and logical exclusive OR operations.
>
> By default, all bits in the set initially have the value false.
>
> Every bit set has a current size, which is the number of bits of space
>   currently in use by the bit set. Note that the size is related to the
>   implementation of a bit set, so it may change with implementation. The
>   length of a bit set relates to logical length of a bit set and is
>   defined independently of implementation.
>
> Unless otherwise noted, passing a null parameter to any of the methods
>   in a BitSet will result in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference between the number itself and
it's representation in the language. For instance, "0xD" (radix 16), "13" (radix 10), "015" (radix 8) and "b1101" (radix 2) are four
different representations referring to the same number.

That said, you can use the "int" primitive data type in the Java language to represent any binary number (as well as any number in any radix), but only in Java 7 you are able to use a [binary literal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000929.html) as you were previously able to use the octal (0) and hexa (0x) literals to represent those numbers, if I understood correctly your question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a computer that uses anything but binary numbers.

The XOR operator in Java is `^`. For example, 5 ^ 3 = 6. The default radix for most number-to-string conversions is 10, but there are several methods which allow you to specify another base, like 2:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(5 ^ 3, 2));
```

*If you are using Java 7,* you can use binary literals in your source code (in addition to the decimal, hexadecimal, and octal forms previously supported).

Comment: That may be, but such computers exist, c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_computer. Of course, the Java Virtual Machine would abstract such implementation details away.

Comment: Oh, sure, they could exist, I just don't think Miguel is confronting one.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them as `byte` arrays, then access the bits individually. Then to XOR them you can merely XOR the bytes (it is a bitwise operation).

Of course it doesn't have to be a byte array (could be an array of `int` types or whatever you want), since everything is stored in binary in the end.