# Why is the output of this array different from the values stored in it?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have an array storing a series of numbers as follows:

```
static final int CodeArray[] ={
            11, 
            011,
            0011,
            1011,
            00011,
            10011,
            01011,
            000011,
            100011,
            010011,
            ...
                            }
```

However when I access the values(using a for loop), it returns the following:

```
11
9
9
1011
9
10011
521
9
100011
4105
```

Why is there a difference in the values being printed from the ones stored?

Comment: The ones stored are the same as the ones printed. Prefix your number with `0b` if you want binary (in Java 7).

Comment: Take a look at the comment by assylias and this wiki article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because putting a `0` before a number turns it into an octal representation, not binary.

So, for example, `011` is octal for decimal `9`, which is what's printed.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971074/working-with-binary-numbers-in-java) to see how to work with binary numbers in Java.

Answer (score 0):

011 is treated as octal not decimal