# Java String to Integer Conversion throws NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I want to cast a string (binary digits) to an `Integer` like this:

```
Integer.parseInt("011000010110")
```

I always get an `NumberFormatException`. Is the number of digits too high?

Comment: It may look like binary, that is going to be interpreted as decimal (and too high).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the string `"011000010110"` is about 11 billion, which is higher than the maximum representable `int`, [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`, 2,147,483,647](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE).  Try

```
Long.parseLong("011000010110")
```

Or, if you meant it as binary, pass a radix of 2 to [`parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Integer.parseInt("011000010110", 2)
```

Comment: As OP says "binary digits", the second version sounds like the right choice. :-)

Comment: I´m confused. if I print the parseInt("binary",2) return the decimal value is printed. I wanted the binary digits just as an integer. Do you understand me? Just the "digits" as halraldK said, not the value.

Comment: In that case parse it to Long, just like the first example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All of Java's number classes are base 10.  However, I found these two options here:

[working with binary numbers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971074/working-with-binary-numbers-in-java)

The BitSet class, or a way to declare an int as a binary number (Java 7+).  The latter may not work for you depending on how you're obtaining these numbers.